# Post body raw json to server retrofit 2?

Tags: retrofit, retrofit2

I have a rest web service on a server with postman. How can I send this request to the service?

```
Body->Raw->JSON(application/json)
[{"NewDigit":"0070297","ReadingStatus":"1","WaterMeterStatus":"1","SCode":"113950","ReportedIssues":"","LNG":"0.0","LAT":"0.0"}]
```

And this is my Header on the Postman:

> `Authorization:bearer 123 Content-Type:application/json`

and server return this to me:

> `"OK"`

Now I want to implement that with retrofit. This is my interface:

```java
public interface IPostReads {
    @Headers( "Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("/readings")
    Call<String> savePost(@Header("Authorization") String Authorization, @Body RequestBody body);
}
```

And this:

```java
public class PostReading {
    private PostReading() {}
    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://185.113.58.156:9100/";

    public static IPostReads getAPIService() {
        return RetrofitClient.getClient(BASE_URL).create(IPostReads.class);
    }
}
```

I have the following code for the post request:

```java
String[] parts = params[0].toString().split(";");
ir.behineh.wepapiinterface.PostReadingToServer.IPostReads taskService = ServiceGenerator.createService(ir.behineh.wepapiinterface.PostReadingToServer.IPostReads.class);
Call<String> tasks = taskService.savePost("bearer "+parts[1].toString(),RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"),parts[0].toString()));
try {
    String x=tasks.execute().body();
    Log.d("behzad post output:",x.toString());

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I get a response with code `200`, but the server returns an error. I think there is something wrong in the body parameter.

What happens?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `/` from `@POST("/readings")` => `@POST("readings")` because you already added it on base url at the end.